# RMQ on a 2d-Array

Tags: algorithm

I am learing about RMQ on an Array which is having a complexity O(logn)
Here is sudo Code:

```
for i=0..N-1: // assuming Arr is indexed from 0
  Table[i][0] = F(Arr[i])
for j=1..k: // assuming N < 2^(k+1)
  for i=0..N-2^j:
    Table[i][j] = F(Table[i][j - 1], Table[i + 2^(j - 1)][j - 1])
```

Can i extend this concept for 2D Array i.e
Matrix of `N x M`. For a Submatrix of `Length X` which starts at `position (a,b)` i have to find the largest element present in a Submatrix.

Comment: It is from an ongoing contest on codechef and believe me this approach will not gonna work, but think of other approach to solve the probem :p

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

In your example `Table[i][j]` is the result of `F` for the range i..i+2^j.

So in 2D you need to have `Table[x][y][j]` that is the result of F for the submatrix (x,y) .. (x+2^j) (y+2^j).

```
for j=1..k: // assuming N < 2^(k+1)
  for x=0..N-2^j:
    for y = 0..N-2^j:
      Table[x][y] = F(Table[x][y][j - 1], 
                      Table[x + 2^(j - 1)][y][j - 1],
                      Table[x][y+2&(j-1)][j-1],
                      Table[x+2^(j-1)][y+2^(j-1)][j-1])
```

Comment: Added, but really you should try to figure out things yourself. You learn much faster that way.